# Is there a mechanism for gcc or makefile which can describe the source file's include files to replace #include "xxxx.h"?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, codeblocks

I am having problems transplanting code from `gcc` makefile to Codeblocks.

In order to debug a project OpenFOAM, I want to transplant it from `gcc` makefile to Codeblocks on Ubuntu. I have used `gcc` makefile to build it successfully. But unfortunately,I use Codeblocks to build it, too many errors occurred in many source files. When I add

```
#include "xxxx.h"
```

to these source files,the problems are solved.

Is there a mechanism for `gcc` or makefile which can describe the source file's include files to replace `#include "xxxx.h"`?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking.  Are you trying to add an extra header (include file) to the start of each compilation?  As a permanent step (modifying all the source code) or as a compile-time only step?  Is there a single header from the source used by all files that you could add the `#include "xxxx.h"` line to, or a small subset of such headers?  Are you asking to analyze which headers are included (`gcc -H` will list the headers as it compiles)?

Comment: does `-I` option NOT work for you?and one question, what is `#inlude`?I saw it has been corrected but change back again

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that your problem is, that the original Makefile tells GCC to "include" one or more header files via the -include option. For details, just consult your Makefile or its output, when you let it run.

When you now use the Codeblocks IDE to compile (instead of having Codeblocks use your Makefile) then just tell Codeblocks to include the same include option(s) in its build process.